# Vote counts for all my comments

Tags: support, comments, votes

Is there a page where I can find all my comments *along* with their vote count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a go with http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/100870/comments-with-score

It relies on SEDE, which is not **quite** up to date, but may provide at least most of what you're looking for. There are refinements which you may like to make, for example ordering by comment score instead of date/time.

I found that my top-voted comment has 38 votes.

Comment: You should [order by score](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/100873/comments-with-score-ordered-by-score).

Comment: Thank you both. This is perfect :)